# Is spring batch right option to payment?

Tags: spring-batch, payment

The process would be like this.

[image]

This job will work for every second.
I'm programming this with spring batch and step will be like, Reader -> Processor(pick random driver) -> writer_1(payments) -> writer_2(db processing) -> writer_3(sending push result messages)

However I'm not sure it is right way for this process.
Because, when an error occurs while inserting or updating data after payment is completed, the batch can re-fetch data every second and attempt re-payment, so countless duplicate payments can occur. Also, the target data for read won't be that much. So I don't think spring batch is right option.

1. spring batch is right option?
2. if exception occurred after payment, should be cancel right away the payment and notify the user? (But batch would repeat to read same data every second)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your diagram and I'm not familiar with spring batch, but I assume all data to be processed is in a database table?

Typically the concurrency you want is implemented by first "reserving" the records to be processed, then going back and marking those as complete

First step is to add a "status" column to your source table with a default value of "Waiting". All new records in this table are automatically set to  "Waiting"

Now use this process:

1. Mark all "Waiting" records as "In Progress" (a single update)
2. Process only records that are in state "In Progress" (note that new records may arrive in this time but they will remain in "Waiting"
3. Each sucessfully processed record now gets set to "Complete"
4. If not successful set to "Failed"
5. Any newly arriving records should automatically be set to "In Progress"

Next time in the loop, only "Waiting" records will be identified for processing. Any that just failed (or are currently being processed by another thread) aren't considered and won't be processed twice.

I suggest that for finer visibility, you also add a batchid, queueddatetime, paymentprocesseddatetime, messagesentdatetime etc. to this table also